# How to get LastSleepTime using CallNtPowerInformation

Tags: c#, winapi

I have code that I going to use for get some power information with CallNtPowerInformation. At the moment I have some problems with getting last sleep time. Can someone help by example?

```
 [DllImport("PowrProf.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint CallNtPowerInformation(
        POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL InformationLevel,
        IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
        int nInputBufferSize,
        ref IntPtr lpOutputBuffer,
        int nOutputBufferSize
    );

 public void GetPowerInfo(int pil)
    {
        IntPtr buff = new IntPtr();
        var result = CallNtPowerInformation(
            (POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL) pil,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            0,
            ref buff,
            Marshal.SizeOf(pil)
        );

        if (result != 0) return;

        var fields = 
            typeof( SYSTEM_BATTERY_STATE ).GetFields( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );
        foreach (var t in fields)
            Debug.WriteLine(
                "{0}: {1}",
                t.Name,
                t.GetValue( buff )
            );
    }
```

Now I getting errorcode 0xc0000023 STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL

Comment: *The lpOutputBuffer buffer receives a ULONGLONG* - so must be 8 byte size. but you use 4 byte size

Comment: @RbMm [link](https://i.imgur.com/zMqOZjK.png)

Comment: What is your declaration of `CallNtPowerInformation`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm sorry. I've added it

Comment: @user3525444 - and so what ? output buffer must be 8 byte size. but not 4 like in your code. as result and `STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL`

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code looks a bit weird to me, however if you wanted to get last sleep time, you either should have used a variable of proper size (long in your case, with the appropriate declaration of CallNtPowerInformation) or manual marshaling (see example below).

Assuming the declaration of **CallNtPowerInformation** as follows:

```
    [DllImport("PowrProf.dll", EntryPoint = "CallNtPowerInformation", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            private static extern int CallNtPowerInformation(
                PowerInformationLevel informationLevel,
                [In]IntPtr lpInputBuffer,
                uint nInputBufferSize,
            [In, Out]IntPtr lpOutputBuffer,
            uint nOutputBufferSize);
```

Then call it like this for example:

```
public long GetLastSleepTime()
{
    IntPtr lastSleep = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        lastSleep = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(long)));

        int ntStatus = CallNtPowerInformation(PowerInformationLevel.LastSleepTime, IntPtr.Zero, 0, lastSleep,
            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(long)));

        if (ntStatus != 0)
            return 0;

        // receives a ULONGLONG that specifies the interrupt-time count, in 100-nanosecond units, at the last system sleep time
        // there are 1e9 nanoseconds in a second, so there are 1e7 100 - nanoseconds in a second

        long lastSleepTimeInSeconds = Marshal.ReadInt64(lastSleep, 0) / 10000000;

        return lastSleepTimeInSeconds;

    }
    finally
    {
        if (lastSleep != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lastSleep);
    }
}
```